# I am getting `unknown mutation type: mobilenav/showmobilenav` toggling a sidebar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to toggle a sidebar, trying to commit a mutation when clicking a button but I keep getting `[vuex] unknown mutation type: mobilenav/showmobilenav` error every time.

I have tried everything I have seen online, but nothing works.

I am also trying to use the module mode instead of classic mode so, my store is structured that way below.

so below are my stores

store/index.js

```js
export const state = () => ({
})
 
export const mutations = ({
})
 
export const actions = ({
})
 
export const getters = ({
})
```

store/mobilenav.js

```js
export const state = () => ({
    mobilenav: false
})

export const mutations = () => ({
    showmobilenav(state) {
        state.mobilenav = true;
    },
    hidemobilenav(state) {
        state.mobilenav = false;
    }
})

export const getters = () => ({
    ismobilenavvisible(state) {
        return state.dropdown;
    }
})
```

the VUE file that calls the mutation on clicking a button

```html
<template>
    <div class="bb" @click="showsidenav">
        <img src="~/assets/svg/burgerbar.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        showsidenav() {
            this.$store.commit("mobilenav/showmobilenav");
            console.log("sidenav shown");
        },
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Check dev tools, that whether the store is properly working or not.

Comment: have you registered the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the exported `mutations` (and `getters`) is a function, but it needs to be an object:

*store/mobilenav.js:*

```js
// export const mutations = () => ({/*...*/}) ❌
export const mutations = {/*...*/} ✅

// export const getters = () => ({/*...*/}) ❌
export const getters = {/*...*/} ✅
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this in your `store/index.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import mobilenav from './mobilenav'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const createStore = () => new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    mobilenav,
  },
})

export default createStore
```

Then inject the store when you load your vue app:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '~/pages/App.vue'
import createStore from '~/store'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if (document.getElementById('app-wrapper')) {
    new Vue({
      store: createStore(),
      render: h => h(App),
    }).$mount('#app-wrapper')
  }
})
```

Comment: The OP is using Nuxt, so that setup is unnecessary.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't see that tag before. Anyway, I'm gonna leave my answer here for the other who doesn't use Nuxt.